# Maven build step to install Node package from private repository

Tags: node.js, git, maven, jenkins, ssh

I have a Maven project that pulls in Node dependencies as part of the build using exec-maven-plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <workingDirectory>src/main</workingDirectory>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>npm-install</id>
            <configuration>
                <executable>npm</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>install</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
```

One of the Node dependencies is hosted in a private Git repository. I don't want enter my password every time I build, so I use the git+ssh protocol in package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "sass-theme": "git+ssh://git@github.com/MyOrg/sass-theme.git#v1.0.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.0"
  }
```

This works fine for me since I regularly connect to my organizations private Git repository using SSH, and the SSH key is not password protected. It also works on our Jenkins server, which has its own SSH key.

The first problem with this approach is some developers in my organization password protect their SSH keys, so they're prompted to enter their password during the build.

The second problem is most developers connect to the repository using HTTPS, so they have to create an SSH key and register it with GitHub. Then, during the build, they're prompted to allow the SSH connection, but it occurs so early in the build that it gets lost in the scroll buffer.

What can I change to make this process more seamless? Can we have a shared SSH key? Or do I need to change the URL of the Node dependency to use git+https?

Answer (score 0):

> The second problem is most developers connect to the repository using HTTPS

1/ They can continue to do that, making sure they are using a **[credential helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials)** to cache their `github.com` username and password (with [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) for instance, you would be using the [Microsoft Git Credential Manager](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows), linked to the [Credential Manager in Windows](https://blog.malwarebytes.com/101/2016/01/the-windows-vaults/))

2/ In order to not change your settings (which are using an ssh url), a developer can use a global configuration like:

```
git config --global url."https://github.com".insteadOf git+ssh://git@github.com
```

That way, any `git@github.com` ssh url would be interpreted/changed as an https one.

Comment: Are you saying developers that use SSH would add that Git config setting, or developers that use HTTPS? Would that prevent anyone from being required to create an SSH key or input a password or respond to any other prompt during the build?

Comment: @DaveKennedy I am saying that developers who wants to use https can do so with your setting (which has an ssh url in it) through a global configuration done on their own workstation. That configuration is only for them and would not prevent anything else.

Comment: I tried adding that Git config setting, moving my ~/.ssh folder, and building the project. What happened surprised me. I expected it to prompt me to enter my password, but it prompted me to allow the SSH connection (The authenticity of host github.com can't be established... Are you sure you want to continue?). Like I mentioned above, it's buried in the scroll buffer so it's hard to determine why it hangs.

Comment: @DaveKennedy Regarding ssh, especially if you move the `~/.ssh` folder (meaning moving the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file as well), such a question is expected. It will be done once only, and recorded in `~/.ssh/known_hosts`

Comment: @DaveKennedy But that can also mean the `.insteadOf git+ssh://git@github.com` setting isn't as well recognized as I hoped: you might have to do some testing here.

Comment: I understand, but I want to avoid any kind of prompt during the build. Most developers contributing to this project aren't Git/Java/Maven/SSH savvy and won't know why it hangs.

Comment: @DaveKennedy Hence my suggestion to use https: with a credential helper, the credentials are cached, and there is no prompt.